# Python output on file and terminal

Tags: python, file, terminal, output

There are times when I want my program to write something on the terminal for immediate inspection and on a file for later use, so I write something like:

```
print "output"
file.write("output")   #the same output as the previous line
```

Is it possible, with python 2.6 or 7, to do it in another, maybe smarter, way?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a function that outputs to both file and terminal in one call?

Comment: `print "output"` is more like `file.write("output"+"\n")`... `print` adds a trailing newline. Just a detail, mind you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could wrap that into a function:

```
>>> def fprint(output):
...    print output
...    with open("somefile.txt", "a") as f:
...        f.write("{}\n".format(output))
```

If this is logging information, you should look into the [logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html). Using the logging module you can easily configure and control multiple destinations for the logging events.

Example from the [logging cookbook](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations):

```
import logging

# set up logging to file - see previous section for more details
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                    filename='/temp/myapp.log',
                    filemode='w')
# define a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# tell the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

# Now, we can log to the root logger, or any other logger. First the root...
logging.info('Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.'

# Now, define a couple of other loggers which might represent areas in your
# application:

logger1 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area2')

logger1.debug('Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim.') # Won't print, file only
logger1.info('How quickly daft jumping zebras vex.') # Printed and to file
logger2.warning('Jail zesty vixen who grabbed pay from quack.') # Printed and to file
logger2.error('The five boxing wizards jump quickly.') # Printed and to file.
```

The above example will write all messages with a logging level of `logging.DEBUG` or higher to a file called `/temp/myapp.log`. Messages with level `logging.INFO` are printed to `sys.stderr`. I highly advocate the use of this module for any logging purposes above simple debug prints.

EDIT: Had the wrong example!

Comment: perhaps append a `'\n'` when writing to the file?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully is not too late, here I go. This worked for me.

```
import sys
import logging

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open(filename, "a")
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.terminal, attr)
    def write(self, message):
        self.log.write(message)     
    def flush(self):
        self.log.flush()
```

Then, it can be used as

```
sys.stdout = Logger("file.txt")
```