# Log terminal output to a text file python

Tags: python, linux

Is there a way to log python print statements to a file

**Method 1**
I know about `python file.py > data.txt` but this will log the crash error in case the script crashes or the last thing the was displayed and won't log anything while the program is running which in my case it will keep on running until I kill it

**Method 2**
I can use subprocess from another file to check the output but this also doesn't work for me since I am planning on using a single compiled python exe (elf in case of linux ) and not two `.py` script or an exe with a `.py`

**method 3**
I tried using `script data.txt`  but this seems to have the same effect as the first method

Note that the goal is to log everything in the terminal before executing the `os.system("clear")` line and everything after the previous clear command

```
from time import time 
from os import system  

def log_terminal():
    ## log whatever text is displayed in the terminal to a text file in that current moment 
    pass

while True:
    print (f"hello time is  {int(time())}")
    log_terminal()
    os.system("clear")
```

Comment: You can write your own utility function which wraps the built-in `print` function and also writes the output to a text file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python output on file and terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250799/python-output-on-file-and-terminal)

Comment: kind of I was looking for something built in  python rather than implementing my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can recommend `logging` for doing this. Simple example:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='output.txt', level=logging.DEBUG, format='')

def we_prints(data):
    logging.info(data)
    print(data)

we_prints("some data we are logging")
```